# iOS Deeplink doesn't work when launching the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I implemented deep links into my app and everything works well, except one thing:

If the app is closed, although the deep link recognize and launch the app, it doesn't call the `openURL` method:

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options`

or

`- (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene openURLContexts:(NSSet<UIOpenURLContext *> *)URLContexts API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0))`

It always calls:

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

and options are nil.

Schema is properly set.

So to recap:

- Deeplinks work well in any case when the app was already open;
- **If the app is closed, the app gets associated with the deep link schema, and it gets opened, however, there's no URL to parse.**

Tested on both, simulator and real device.

Does anyone have clue on why this could happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have window scenes, it all depends on your implementation of [`scene:willConnectToSession:options:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3197914-scene?language=objc). The URL is in the `options`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I literally missed checking this method. However, it seems is only working in certain scenarios. If I close the app completely and open a deep link, it doesn't seem is called. The first time I tried it worked but probably because it restored an existing session paused in the background. Does it make sense for you?

Comment: Well, I'm not obligated to use universal links. For my purpose, a schema is enough and easy to set up. Everything, indeed, works properly, except this aspect, and only on iOS (on tvOS it works well). 

The problem is not the `userActivities`, once the method is called, everything goes well. The problem is that, that method is not called when the app is invoked from a deeplink, while it is closed. I got it called just it once and I didn't figure out why.